# How do I make this inner ring thicker - in other words make the inner white circle's radius less

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I suspect a small change to the following snippet will do what I want:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .startAngle(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .endAngle(function(d) {
    return d.x + d.dx;
  })
  .outerRadius(function(d) {
    return Math.sqrt(d.y) * .9;
  })
  .innerRadius(function(d) {
    return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy);
  });
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is to make the inner ring as thick as the outer ring in the following - reason being is that I want to add text to each arc so both rings need to be quite thick:

http://plnkr.co/edit/zLOTF2o6ylKvHKw8DRU7?p=preview

Comment: In your concrete example the `innerRadius` is greater than `outerRadius`. So according to the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#arc_outerRadius) the radii were flipped. To make the inner white circle smaller you have to decrease the outerRadius, e.g. `return Math.sqrt(d.y) * 0.4`.

Comment: @gus27 try your suggestion in the plunk - doesn't work

Comment: I just rechecked the plunk and when I replace the 0.9 by 0.4 on line 64 the inner circle gets smaller. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @gus27 apologies - as I think you've worked out I was keen on both rings remaining the same width - so my original question was vague and should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the inner ring showing the same width as the outer ring you have to use a linear function in `outerRadius`/`innerRadius` and not use a non-linear function like `sqrt`.

E.g. you can try this:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .endAngle(function(d) {
        return d.x + d.dx;
    })
    .outerRadius(function(d) {
        return (d.y+d.dy) / radius;
    })
    .innerRadius(function(d) {
        return d.y / radius;
    });
```

In your plunk it looks like this:

[image]

**This is subject to the condition** that your input parameters (here `d.dy`) are equal. In your plunk example `d.dy` is always 7500. So to make the inner ring thicker than the outer ring you have to tweak the input parameters.